# no code error in my mysql query yet no results

Tags: mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE wreport13 
AS 
SELECT customers.CName, customers.CIDCard, customers.Cphone, customers.infection, users.UName, authlist.AuthType, checkup.comment 
FROM ((((checkup 
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.CID=checkup.CID) 
INNER JOIN users ON users.UID=checkup.EID) 
INNER JOIN uauth ON users.UID=uauth.UID)
INNER JOIN authlist ON authlist.AID=uauth.AuthID) 
WHERE (checkup.Result=1) 
  and (checkup.QID=9) 
  and (checkup.cdate='2020-05-23') 
  and (uauth.astatus=1)
```

this query should result 4 records but nothing comes out.

please help me to find the error,

when i used this  below query

```sql
    SELECT cdate,COUNT(CID) AS customers
      FROM (checkup
      INNER JOIN questionaire ON questionaire.QID=checkup.QID)
    WHERE checkup.Result=1 and checkup.QID=9 
    GROUP BY cdate
```

and result is

```
cdate         customers
2020-05-23     4
2020-05-25     1
2020-05-30     3
2020-05-31     2
```

the first query is meant to extract the details of the first row of the above query

Comment: Does commenting `CREATE TABLE wreport13 AS` gives SELECT query which' output consists from 4 rows?

Comment: nope, still no output but when i test the data using other query it outputs 4 rows

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i didn't get what you mean #Strawberry. does this mean that my question not include enough data for you to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was a mistake in inner join key with customers table

```sql
    SELECT customers.CName, customers.CIDCard, customers.Cphone, customers.infection, 
       users.UName, authlist.AuthType, checkup.comment 
    FROM ((((checkup 
             INNER JOIN customers ON customers.CID=checkup.CuID) 
            INNER JOIN users ON users.UID=checkup.EID) 
           INNER JOIN uauth ON users.UID=uauth.UID)
          INNER JOIN authlist ON authlist.AID=uauth.AuthID) 
    WHERE (checkup.Result=1) 
           and (checkup.QID=9) 
           and (checkup.cdate='2020-05-23') 
           and (uauth.astatus=1)
```

Comment: Never use brackets in the FROM clause unless you know exactly why you are doing it. In shown case - remove them all. They are unnecessary and even harmful.